# Anime about demons that take over Earth they were created by humans. Girls called fairies fight them to take earth back

Tags: story-identification, anime

Anime about girls called fairies that fight demons on Earth. The main character is a guy that fought one of the demons with 3 friends, 2 of the friends died in the fight and he killed the demon but got frozen in time.

When he gets unfrozen he gets a job to look after the girls. During the job he learns the girls are called fairies and use swords that no one else can use to kill the demons. The fairies don’t live past the age of 15 and die to the demons or to the memories of there past lives. So he teaches them how to fight and also repairs their swords in the hopes they would live longer.

He falls in love with one of the girls/fairies; she has blue hair and is the strongest fighter and she dies in the end and gets reborn again. That’s all I can remember, doesn’t anyone know what this is?

Comment: Do you possibly remember when you read it? And what language it may have originally aired in, if not English did you watch a dubbing of the anime? If you haven't already, can I suggest you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and [edit] in any extraneous details you may remember!

Comment: I liked the premise of the anime, but then you spoiled the end :(

Comment: It's kind of more complicated than described ... and weirder, especially near the end. It's not the greatest show ever, but worth a watch (and has a beautiful rendition of Scarborough Fair in it).

Answer (score 9):

The series is called ["What Do You Do at the End of the World? Are You Busy? Will You Save Us?"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WorldEnd) (*Shūmatsu Nani Shitemasu ka? Isogashii Desu ka? Sukutte Moratte Ii Desu ka?* or WorldEnd/SukaSuka for short).

Per the Wikipedia article's plot summary:

> It's been over 500 years since the human race almost went extinct at the hands of the fearsome and mysterious "Beasts". The surviving races now make their homes, towns, and cities up on floating islands in the sky to keep out of reach of all but the most mobile of Beasts. Only a group of young girls, dubbed the Leprechauns, can wield the ancient Dug Weapons needed to fend off invasions from those dangerous creatures. Into the peoples' unstable and fleeting lives, where a simple call to certain death could come at any moment, enters an unlikely character: a mysterious man who lost everything in his final battle five hundred years ago, and had awakened from a long, icy slumber. Unable to fight any longer, the man, Willem, becomes the father those kids never had, caring for and nurturing them even as he struggles to come to terms with his new life, in which he feels the pain of helplessly waiting for his loved ones to return home from battle that his 'Daughter' once felt for him so long ago. Together, Willem and the leprechauns gradually come to understand what family means and what is truly worth protecting in their lives.

Noting that while in Japanese the girls were called "Leprechauns", in the Crunchyroll subtitles they became "Fairies".

Comment: That is the right one thank you.

Comment: Cool, there should be a thing you can click underneath the voting buttons to accept this answer as correct

Answer (score -1):

It's name is "Worldend"

You can find out more about it here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WorldEnd

Comment: This is the same title suggested by ConMan's answer, which the question writer already confirmed as correct. Moreover, while a wikipedia link is probably not going to break, pointing out *in the answer* similarities (and differences) between the suggested title and the question would make for a better answer.